# User has does not have permission to be mentioned

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We have a TFS user who appears to have the same permissions as a colleague in their team. However this user can't be [@mentioned](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/productivity/productivity-tips#mention-person-id) despite having the ability to open and close and otherwise edit the bug that they can't be mentioned in.

The following error is emailed to me following attempting to `@mention` this user.

> @Joe Bloggs cannot be mentioned in the Bug 41729. The user does not have
>   sufficient permissions.

We can't see any differences between a user that can be tagged and one that can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were getting this same error.

- Went into the project settings -> security.
- Clicked "remove" on that user
- at which point the "remove" changed into an "undo".
- Clicked the "undo".

Now we are no longer seeing this error.  Seems like something internally just needed to be recombobulated :-)

Comment: I'll give this a go.

Comment: @Fishcake did you manage to solve it? I am having the same issue but I cannot figure out where is the problem. I was changing some permissions but even after putting everything as it was, I am having this issue. In my case, the user cannot even access the project.

Comment: @sfratini Yes, this solution worked for us. Thanks for the reminder to accept this answer!

Comment: @Fishcake Thanks! I solved it too but my issue was different. I ignored that the "View project level information" permission was to give access to the project. I assume it was some project detail information and I accidentally took the access from some users by making the permission Deny. Something to keep in mind too. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If this is the solution, then this clearly is an Azure DevOps bug and should be resolved internally.

Comment: Note that removing the user only works if you've added them explicitly.  I have not. My project is set to Enterprise so they already have permissions.  The can be linked as mentioned and also the work item can be assigned to that user.  So it's only the system generated email that is faulty.

Comment: Similar to A. Wentzel but in Azure DevOps: our users are managed through Azure AD groups. Sometimes we need to remove the user from the DevOps org and have them rejoin before this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the user exists and can be mentioned with "Joe Bloggs" then they do not have read permission on the bug you are referring to. You should go back and check what group membership they have in the project.

Comment: I can confirm that the user exists, has read permission on the bug, can comment on the bug and change status of the bug. They just can't be mentioned.

Comment: I experienced the same thing as Fishcake, also, the project is set to Enterprise so the entire company should have read permissions as I understand it?